# Roslyn - How to got line by line through a method?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Is their a way in Roslyn to go through a Method in C# line by line?

What I try to do is analyze comments inside a UnitTest do build a Documentation:

This is a Example Test which I want to analyze

```
 [TestClass]
    public class ClassToAnalyze
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void MethodToAnalyze()
        {
            // * Start Testing
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
            // * Test something other
            var text = new string("foobar");
            Assert.IsNotNull(text);
            // ** Test additional strings
            Assert.AreEqual("foobar",text);
            // + Test Numbers
            TestNumbers();
        }

        private void TestNumbers()
        {
            // ** Test integer
            var count = 3;
            Assert.AreEqual(3, count);
            // ** Test Double
            var pi = 3.14;
            Assert.IsTrue(pi > 0);
        }
    }
```

You can see the comments which are marked which an asterix, this is doc level 1 an the one with 2 asterix are Level 2. Like an unsorted list in markdown.

But the comment with the + sign marks that after this their is a method-call where are also comments include for the documentation.

For Example:
I analyze the code of the Testmethod, this works totaly fine. But the Comment *// + Test Numbers* indicates that their are additional comments in the methods *TestNumbers()*. I already build a way to analyze the Comments in *TestNumbers()*
but I do not get a connection during analyze between the comment *// + Test Numbers* and the call *TestNumbers()* in the line after.

What I tried:

I tried this but I only managed to get a list of statements and I did not find a way to get the Trivia before every statement.

How could I do this?

```
foreach (var method in _classDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>())
{
     var blockSyntax = methodDeclarationSyntax.Body;
     var syntaxNodes = blockSyntax.ChildNodes();
}
```

Comment: One option is to do ToFullString on the method body, and then split it manually as a string.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you tring to analyze comments? The roslyn apis are about walking a tree looking for specific shapes or types. You could look for all the new line trivia but without knowing what you are trying to do it is hard to suggest anything

Comment: @JonathonMarolf I add some code and try to explain my problem with an example, I hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of try and error it is pretty easy. The thing to use is CSharpSyntaxWalker and give him a BlockSyntax.

```
public class MethodBodySyntaxWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{

    public override void VisitLocalDeclarationStatement(LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.HasLeadingTrivia)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(node.GetLeadingTrivia().ToFullString().Trim());
        }
        Trace.WriteLine(node.ToString());
    }

    public override void VisitExpressionStatement(ExpressionStatementSyntax node)
    {
        if (node.HasLeadingTrivia)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(node.GetLeadingTrivia().ToFullString().Trim());
        }
        Trace.WriteLine(node.ToString());
    }
}
```